# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement search (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for search

Tags: python-3.x

`pip install search` gives error like that:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement search (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for search

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly ? the error is telling you that there's no pypi package with the name `search` .

Comment: That command `pip install search` was deduced by an editor, it's unclear if it really is what the author is asking/doing.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because PyPi cannot provide any compatible installation files.

There is a `search` package on PyPi: https://pypi.org/project/search/. It seems it's a **dead** package, as it does not contain a description, provide downloadable source codes, or link to a code repository. Its only version was released in 2012 and the homepage link leads to MailQQ login page.

Maybe you are looking for [some other search-* package](https://pypi.org/search/?q=search).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are experiencing issues with launching codimension:
https://github.com/SergeySatskiy/codimension

Issue appears because pip installer does not copy "search" folder from this project, you need to manually copy it from git to fix the issue.